# how can i simplify this return statement?

Tags: javascript

> is it possible simplify .map's return statement? I want to add key for each element in the array, and transform arr to array of object. thanks!

```
let arr = ['c:/a.txt', 'b:/c.txt', 'd:/e.txt'];
let arrObj = arr.map((file) => return {path: file});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
let arr = ['c:/a.txt', 'b:/c.txt', 'd:/e.txt'],
    arrObj = arr.map(path => ({ path }));

console.log(arrObj);
```